# How to extract the details from the JIRA development panel in winform using C#?

Tags: jira

I am able to fetch various details through REST API like the Client Viewable, Status, Lifecycle Step etc.

Now I want to fetch the review link from the development panel from the JIRA.

Is there any API which can help me achieve it?

Comment: Anyone who can help with this?
Any links or documents?

Comment: Any expert/newbie to help with some suggestions?